# Verifying login to website via powershell - do I need to scrape regardless?

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I need to test if a set of default credentials work for a site programmatically.

Right now I have two options at my disposal. The app will login if I pass a url like - https://this.com/app/loginprocess.aspx?username=user1&password=pass1.

I can also use POST and `Innvoke-WebRequest` to sign into the site. Something like;

```
$UserCredentials = Get-Credential
$InvokeResponse  = Invoke-WebRequest $Url -SessionVariable MyInvokeSession

$form = $InvokeResponse.Forms
$form.fields['Username'] = '$UserCredentials.UserName'
$form.fields['Password'] = $UserCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$InvokeResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($Url + $form.Action) -WebSession $MyInvokeSession -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
```

My first question is - no matter which of the two methods I use, I must scrape the webpage to check if the login was successful, correct?

My second question is - Is scraping the page the only way to check if the login worked? If so what is a good way to scrape for a constant value?

Thanks.

The urls are always structured the same, and the form is always the same.

Comment: An HTTP Request should send back a HTTP Response with an error indicating the login failed.  You are using HTTPS (secure) and will not get a response if there isn't a common certificate installed in both client and server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the site was coded - but every HTTP request returns a Status code - and generally you should be able to use this to validate a login without having to look at the actual response itself.

Take a look at the value of `$InvokeResponse.StatusCode` after making the request. Try a correct and incorrect login - does it return the same status code or different? If you get a `200` or similar for valid login attempt and a `403` for the invalid login attempt those are standard success/fail codes for a login and you can use them in your logic. Another way of testing if a login worked is trying to login, then access a page that only works for logged in users (try the same test on the response code of that page). If both tests give the same code for success and fail you need to use the content to decide if you logged in or not.

You can check the Status code like this:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.google.com/

Write-Host "Response code $($r.StatusCode)";
if($r.StatusCode -lt 400){
    Write-Host "Probably OK";
}else{
    Write-Host "Something went wrong";
}
```

and i get the output:

```
Response code 200
Probably OK
```

FYI codes starting `2` are Success(200, 201, 204 are common ones), codes starting `3` are redirects(301, 304 etc), codes starting `4` is a client error (404 not found, 403 not authorized etc) and codes starting `5` something went wrong server side. BUT its totally arbitrary what code the programmer that made that page decided to send back for any given input so test thoroughly :-)

---

Side note - use POST not GET when sending credentials. By default most servers will write GET request parameters to its log files in plain text and not for POST requests. You might want to change that password just in case